# execve error: no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait, execve

I'm trying to write a program to execute and schedule a list of processes. My code for main.c is below. When run, I receive an error from perror saying there is no such file or directory. I'm guessing this is because the files/programs in my files.txt are not binary executables but I'm not sure how to fix this. files.txt contains the list of programs I want to run. They have all been converted to binary executables already. programs is an array containing the four programs that have been read by the readPrograms function

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    pid_t pid[50];
    pid_t wpid;
    int i, j;
    int status = 0;
    char *newenvp[] = {NULL};
    char *newargv[] = {"./files.txt", NULL};

    printf("Before forking in the parent\n");
    int numProgs = readPrograms();

    for (i=0; i<numProgs; i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] < 0) {
            perror("fork error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid[i] == 0) {
            printf("Child process running\n");
            execve(programs[i], newargv, newenvp);
            perror("execve error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<numProgs; i++) {
        wait(&status);
    }
    return 0;
}
char* programs[50];
int readPrograms();
```

files.txt below

```
./first
./second
./third
./fourth
```

(I did "cc first.c -o first" for all of these files respectively)

Comment: Use `strace -f -e execve` to look at the actual syscalls being made. If the error is what @R suspects, it'll be plain to see. (If that isn't illuminating, I'd take off the `-e execve` filter and take a more general look for a syscall returning ENOENT).

Comment: ...by the way, it would be more conventional to pass your target file as `argv[1]`, not `argv[0]`; unless one has a specific reason for it to be otherwise, `argv[0]` is by convention the name of the program being run.

Comment: the parameter newargv[] is not being correctly set.  it should contain newargv[0] = programs[i];  newargv[1] = NULL;

Comment: @user3629249 It was working as I wanted it to with R's fix. When I tried this way, (which I'm sure is correct) I got a segfault. Not sure how to fix this unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the bug is in the code you're not showing, `readPrograms`. Most likely you're reading the lines of the text file with `fgets` and each string has a newline on the end of it, whereas your filenames don't have newlines in them.

Comment: fixed. much appreciated